# HTML is not appearing correctly? (laravel-dompdf package)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, frontend

I want to achieve a layout like this:

[image]

But Im having like this:

[image]

The c inside the div ".post_admin" is in front of the b of the div ".post_date" and there is no separation between the ".post_date" and ".post_admin" divs.

Do you know what can be the issue? I have this code in a file and the HTML and css in this file is rendered in a pdf file that the user downloads:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>


      .wrapper{
        width: 600px;
        display:block;
        margin: auto;
        border:1px solid gray;
        text-align:center;
      }

      .post-title{
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        padding:20px;
        text-align:left;
      }

      .post-info{
        width:100%;
        display: flex;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .post-date{
        border-right:1px solid gray;
        padding: 20px;
        flex: 1;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .post-admin{
        padding:20px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        text-align: left;
        flex: 1;
      }

      .post-category{
        border-top:1px solid gray;
        text-align: left;
        padding:10px;
      }

      .post-tags{
        border-top:1px solid gray;
        text-align: left;
        padding:10px;
      }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      @foreach($posts as $post)



      <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="post-title">
          a
        </div>

        <div class="post-info">

          <div class="post-date">
            b
          </div>
          <div class="post-admin">
            c
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="post-category">
          <span>d</span>
          <span> e</span>
        </div>

        <div class="post-tags">
          <span>f</span>
          <span>g</span>
        </div>
      </div>





      @endforeach
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think the wrapper should be `display: flex;` and the children `flex: 1;`..etc, then deal later with aligning the elements

Comment: Thanks but like that dont also dont appear correctly.

Comment: see this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc&t=1088s
and i'd recommend using css grid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o&t=53s

Comment: Could it be a browser issue? I copied your HTML + CSS into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7tyv4Lh/) and it displays in the layout you are wanting.

Comment: Thanks, that HTML and css is used to style a pdf file. In the jsfiddle it also appears correct but on the pdf file it appears like it is in the image.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that part.  Do you know what engine/software is being used to render HTML in the pdf?  I would guess that it's using an older version of WebKit that doesn't fully support flexbox.  Otherwise I can't guess at a solution without more detail as the html and css is technically correct.

Comment: Im using this package "https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf". Do you know why b and c are not appearing properly with floats? (http://jsfiddle.net/zgy86wfj)

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhep7096/).  The cells did not display correctly for you b/c your .post-date and .post-admin div `widths` need to be 50% and `heights` need to be 100%.  Further, you only need to `float:right` the .post-admin; .post-date does not need to have a layout value.  Sorry we couldn't figure out the flex issue.  I'm not a big fan of floats but in this situation it seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much for the package you are using to convert HTML into PDF b/c I have no experience with it but my guess is that it does not fully support flexbox since [the css is correct for the layout you want](https://jsfiddle.net/s7tyv4Lh/).

With flexbox off the toolbelt you may try to manually style the .post-info cells w/ `display: inline-block`, `width: 50%`, and `height:100%`.  You can give .post-admin `float: right` layout to [eliminate the space between inline-block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

All together:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.post-title{
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-info{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.post-date{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-admin{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-category{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-tags{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="post-title">a</div>
  <div class="post-info">
    <div class="post-date">b</div>
    <div class="post-admin">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-category">
    <span>d</span>
    <span>e</span>
  </div>
  <div class="post-tags">
    <span>f</span>
    <span>g</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that the HTML also dont appears correctly.

Comment: You may want to reach out to the developer directly at his GitHub [issues page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues)